# Ubuntu is unable to detect my GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop, 20.04, dual-graphics

I have an MSI laptop which was working fine with Ubuntu 18, but I decided to upgrade. It has one of these dual graphics setups, which and Intel HD 630 and a NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB. On Ubuntu 18, I simply get the NVIDIA GPU to work by selecting its drivers on the "Additional Drivers" tab under "Software and Updates", but on this version of Ubuntu, my GPU doesn't appear there any more.

Also, if I type this in the console: $ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'

This is the only line I get: 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)

Just in case, my laptop model is this: https://es.msi.com/Laptop/GL72VR-7RFX

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to say that **I also have Windows on dual boot and the GPU works perfectly fine there. Also, it is not disabled on the BIOS or something like that.** I don't think that is even possible on my BIOS either.

Edit 2:

> lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 630
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

Looking at the output, I don't know why it says that my processor is an Intel Xeon... it's actually a i7-7700HQ.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. If it still doesn't show up, post output of `lspci`.

Comment: The GPU is disabled in BIOS or broken. `lspci` shows all devices available.

Comment: So, if the GPU is disabled in BIOS or broken, how can it work perfectly under Windows? Please read the question.

Comment: That's a mystery.

Comment: If it is a bug, how can I report it to the developers?

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug linux`. But you will be ask to test on the latest mainline kernel.